# What is php's performance on directly accessing array's row with key specified

Tags: php, arrays, performance, key

I have a question regarding array's performance.... how does php handle array keys? I mean if I do something like `$my_city = $cities[15];` .... does php directly access the exact row item in `$cities` array or does php iterate trough array until it finds the matched row?

and if it access the row directly... is there a difference in performance between an array with 100 rows and array with 100,000 rows?

like in this example
`$my_city = $cities[15];`

Comment: this may help u a bit  : http://blog.red-stars.net/uncategorized/php-array-performance/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's arrays are implemented as hash tables, so the elements are accessed as directly as possible, without iterating through everything. Read more about the algorithm here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: I guess hash table more relevant to case with associative array (with pair key values).

Comment: @Artem Since there's only one type of array in PHP I suspect there's no real difference (though I'm not 100% certain of that). Numerically indexed arrays are just associative arrays with numeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

It access it directly. Behind the scene everything is memory pointers arithmetic. I can hardly believe that array concept or implementation in PHP somehow differs from  other languages like C, Java or C#.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is inside the array too.

```
// $my_city is a reference to the variable
$cities[15] = new stdobj();    
$my_city = $cities[15];

// $my_city is a copy of the array row
$cities[15] = 'foobar';    
$my_city = $cities[15];
```

May not be a direct answer to you question, but a reference to an object usually uses less memory than a variable copy.

Answer (score -2):

there is always an obvious difference in performance between an array with 100 rows and array with 100,000 rows

Comment: In a properly implemented hash algorithm it should make little to no difference.

Comment: at least it will take more time to initialize and consume more memory. and such hash navigation will cost you something too.

Comment: The pure access times will not really be influenced by the array size. Initialization or memory consumption of the array itself are beside the point.